# How to load a file (MYFILE.CSV) into Oracle table (BLOBTABLE), using SQL*Loader?

Tags: oracle, blob, oracle12c, sql-loader

This is just an effort to share a solution that we used in our organisation for the benefit of all.

Aim: We have a file `MYFILE.CSV`. We need to create a table in Oracle database and load this file into that table.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table BLOBTABLE(FILENAME blob);
```

Create a text file, `MYDATA.TXT` with the text `MYFILE.CSV`.

Control File: `MYDATA.CTL`

```
load data
infile MYDATA.TXT
truncate into BLOBTABLE
fields terminated by ‘,’ trailing nullcols
(
input_file filler,
FILENAME lobfile(input_file)
terminated by eof 
)
```

Place all the three files, `MYFILE.CSV`, `MYDATA.CTL` and `MYDATA.TXT` in a folder. In command prompt, change directory to that folder and type the below command.

```
sqlldr userid=user/pwd@sid control=mydata.ctl log=mydata.log bad=mydata.bad
```

Hit ENTER!!!

Comment: Well, that won't work. You forgot the TABLE keyword in the APPEND line. Single quotes are invalid (look kind of *fancy*, ASCII 145; should be ASCII 39). Also, I'd say that something like that belongs to your BLOG, not Stack Overflow. Other than that, yes - it's OK.

Comment: @Littlefoot: You are right with respect to the table clause. We used truncate and not append as we did not need the old data after new load. I have change it now. Single quotes are valid and it works. Also technical solutions like these are much relevant in Stack Overflow and will be helpful to others.  https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/load-lob-data-using-sql-loader